# How Can I Achieve Horizontal Orientation Inside Vertical in XML

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a layout file which is used to inflate a list view. So I want to change the way the TextView inside my LinearLayout are display. currentrly, Textview displaying text "localhost" is in horizontal orientation with the other two TextView which display ip address and mac address. TextView with ip add and mac are in a vertical orientation with each other. [see Screenshot here.](http://pctechtips.org/apps/screenshot/listview.png) I want to change it so that Textview displaying "localhost" is in vertical orientation and ip add and mac address textview are under in next to each other. something like this
localhost.net.com
192.168.1.2 | 00:23:ff:33:ee:21
I don't want to put localhost textview in a line by itself as this will throw off my code design. here's the code for layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/host_icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_computer_white_36dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/host_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="LOCALHOST"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ip_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                tools:text="192.168.10.100"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mac_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="aa:bb:cc:00:11:22"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/port_scan_arrow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_next_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Android, inflating views are a quite heavy operation, and the imbrication of many layouts is not really performant. Try to use a ConstraintLayout when you have imbricated layouts.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout